# Loading image failed in Marshmallow using BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android

I am using this code to load images

```
async Task<BitmapFactory.Options> GetBitmapOptionsOfImageAsync()
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options
                                    {
                                        InJustDecodeBounds = true
                                    };

    // The result will be null because InJustDecodeBounds == true.
    Bitmap result=  await BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync(Resources, Resource.Drawable.samoyed, options);

    int imageHeight = options.OutHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.OutWidth;

    _originalDimensions.Text = string.Format("Original Size= {0}x{1}", imageWidth, imageHeight);

    return options;
}
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/

It works fine except in Marshmallow `options` returns null. What am I missing?

Comment: That is working fine for me, using `Xamarin.Android` Version: 6.1.99.224 on Api 23 (Marshmallow).. What version of `Xamarin.Android` are you using?

Comment: I am using `Xamarin.Android` version  6.0.3.5 on Api 23.

Comment: I'm getting error in this line:  Bitmap result=  await BitmapFactory.DecodeResourceAsync(Resources, ...)     My app doesn't recognize Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is having the same problem. I've found that this problem only occurs when debugging using Visual Studio emulator  with API 23 (Marshmallow). I haven't tested it using other emulator though.

When I debug using a physical device, the problem did not occur.

Just be sure to select `Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)` for `Compile using Android version:` and `Target Android version:` in `Application properties`.

When compiling a `Release` version, make sure to set the `Linker properties` under `Android Options` to `Sdk Assemblies Only`